# How can I filter the text from an input box?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this script to accept certain characters for an input box, but i need to modify it. I want to accept only letters, numbers and one blank space. How i can do this?

```
var r={
'special':/[\W]/g,
'quotes':/['\''&'\"']/g,
'notnumbers':/[^\d]/g
}

function valid(o,w){
o.value = o.value.replace(r[w],'');
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
[\d*\w*\s{1}]
```

- `\d*` zero or more numbers
- `\w*` zero or more letters
- `\s{1}` one white
  space character

Putting them in a character class `[...]` allows them to be in any order.

here is a [good site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to build and test regular expressions.

Comment: can you elaborate on `add` and `does not work`? added where? how are you calling it? what are you expecting it to do? what errors are there in the console?

Comment: added [\d*\w*\s{1}] on /.../g